# Text not aligning vertically in a flex block

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

```css
.account-select-block {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.account-select-icon {
  flex: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.account-select-item {
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
  background: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: border 0.1s ease;
  text-align: left;
}

.account-select-remove {
  flex: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #ff5200;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="account-select-block">
  <div class="account-select-icon">
    <i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="account-select-item">
    <h3>Account Name</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="account-select-remove">
    <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the end icons are aligning vertically but text in the middle block doesn't

What am I doing wrong?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7su954x3/

Comment: @Condor it align the whole `account-select-item` block if it's not 100%, but no the text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the margin from the heading:

```css
.account-select-block {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.account-select-icon {
  flex: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.account-select-item {
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
  background: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: border 0.1s ease;
  text-align: left;
}

.account-select-remove {
  flex: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #ff5200;
  color: #fff;
}

/* add this */
.account-select-item h3 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="account-select-block">
  <div class="account-select-icon">
    <i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="account-select-item">
    <h3>Account Name</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="account-select-remove">
    <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Didn't realise you were setting the line height manually to vertically centre, if you don't want to do that then you would have to make each child flex too and apply align items to them:

```css
.account-select-block {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.account-select-icon {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.account-select-item {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  flex-grow:1;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
  background: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: border 0.1s ease;
  text-align: left;
}

.account-select-remove {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #ff5200;
  color: #fff;
}

/* add this */
.account-select-item h3 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="account-select-block">
  <div class="account-select-icon">
    <i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="account-select-item">
    <h3>Account Name</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="account-select-remove">
    <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution works if you are certain your text will never be longer than one line, since it relies on line-height. Also you can not change the height on `account-select-box` without breaking the alignment.

Answer (score 1):

In your question you ask how to align in flexbox. However in your code `.account-select-item` is not a flexbox.

Instead you seem to be using an old styling 'hack' using line-height. This will fall apart if you ever decide to change `.account-select-block`'s height or line-height.

```css
.account-select-block {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  /* line-height: 50px; */
}

.account-select-icon {
  flex: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.account-select-item {
  display: flex; /* NEW */
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center; /* NEW */
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
  background: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: border 0.1s ease;
  text-align: left;
}

.account-select-remove {
  flex: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #ff5200;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="account-select-block">
  <div class="account-select-icon">
    <i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="account-select-item">
    <h3>Account Name</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="account-select-remove">
    <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
.account-select-item {
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
  background: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: border 0.1s ease;
  text-align: left;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}
```